# AndroidManifest.xml:N: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest>

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement flutterlocalnotification in my app but unfortunately its raising an error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X688B in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\PPlanner\myplanner\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             28.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is the manifest debug file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myplanner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <!--
         The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="myplanner" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myplanner.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the manifest main file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myplanner">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

   <application
        android:label="myplanner"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                    <receiver
              android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: It's complaining about the merged AndroidManifest.xml. Have you added any library recently? When you open the file are there any noticeable errors?

Comment: Thank you for the reply  @jmc  Yes I added the flutterlocalnotification . There are no noticeable errors when I open the file . I tried flutter clean but it's not working

Comment: I checked that library's GitHub issues to see if anyone has similar issues but couldn't find any, I assume the issue is specific to your project but it's almost impossible to offer advice unless I can see additional output from Gradle that shows the specific error or what went wrong.

Does running `gradle.bat :app:processDebugResources --stacktrace` in the `android` folder show anything?

Also a bit of a shot in the dark, but make sure `flutter doctor -v` doesn't highlight any problems (I don't think it's related to this issue however)

Comment: This is the output of gradle.bat :app:processDebugResources --stacktrace       * What went wrong:
Project 'app' not found in root project 'myplanner'.

Comment: what action are you triggering that causes VS Code to move the receiver element out of your application element to under your manifest element?

Comment: when i execute the flutter run command

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty useful here:

> ...\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: unexpected element  found in

You put a `<receiver>` directly under your manifest debug file's `<manifest>` element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myplanner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
    ...
    <application
        ...
```

See the [`<receiver>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element) documentation, which states that they're supposed to go directly inside a [`<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) element.

So move your `<receiver>` to go directly inside your `<application>` element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myplanner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
    ...
    <application
    ...
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>
        ...
```

Comment: Visual studio is putting the <receiver> block  itself at the bottom of the manifest file.

When I remove the whole receiver block it puts it back in. I have tried moving it inside the <application> but again the VS Code moves it back outside.

Comment: This worked for me, I had <application XXX></application> in a line above the <receiver> block. I have just put </application> afer the </receiver> block closing and now everything is working fine